# Image gets distorted and blurry in Canvas using fabricjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I am uploading an image and then displaying it in canvas using fabricjs. Uploaded image is fine. But when I load it in canvas its distorted and blurry.
Here is the code I am using to load image in canvas.

```
$("#canvas_area").append('<canvas id="c"></canvas>');
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setDimensions({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
 }, {
    cssOnly: true
 });
 var imgElement = response.uploaded_file;
 fabric.Image.fromURL(imgElement, function (img) {
     img.set({
         borderColor: 'red',
         cornerColor: 'green',
         cornerSize: 6,
         transparentCorners: false
    });
    if (img.height > img.width) {
        img.scaleToHeight(80);
    }
    if (img.height < img.width) {
        img.scaleToWidth(120);
    }
    if (img.height == img.width) {
        img.height = 100;
        img.width = 200;
    }
    img.set('left', 10);
    img.set('top', 10);
    img.setCoords();
    canvas.add(img);
});
```

Also it resizes the square image (image width == image height) into rectangular shaped image.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/Vp6wa/183/?

Comment: Why does it resize the square image (image width == image height) into rectangular shaped image. I am having this problem too.

Answer (score 2):

Your code sets in the third `if`:

```
if (img.height == img.width) {
    img.height = 100;
    img.width = 200;
}
```

so any square (1:1) image is distorted to be a 2:1 image.

I'd write the resizing like this:

```
if (img.height > img.width) {
    img.scaleToHeight(80);
}
if (img.height <= img.width) { //include square images here
    img.scaleToWidth(120);
}
```